# How to switch voltage using transistor

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, bjt

I have a 5V voltage source with 2.5A current as input. I want to have this source in the output. I use a microcontroller. I can't use a relay because it takes up a lot of space.

I first used [this](https://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/mosfet-voltage-level-converter) circuit for this, but this wasn't suitable for me because I had a voltage drop which wasn't manageable.

[image]

How can I switch input voltage as output?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What will be connected to the 5V output.

Comment: Might want to look at "load switches".

Comment: When the switch is done, connect the input voltage to the output voltage

Comment: What device are you trying to supply power to?  The solution looks different between, for example, a motor and a microprocessor.

Comment: Samsung phone that is fast charging. It needs more than 2 amps when charging.

Comment: The circuit is not meant to switch loads, but convert voltage levels. It reads in the web page you linked to.

Comment: @mehdializade What precisely are your space requirements?

Comment: @jonk ,In terms of height 5 mm. Length and width 2 * 3 cm.